# rails の migration で reversible な change_column はありますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails の migration で、今ある nullable なカラムを not null にするときには、このように変更するかと思います。

```
def change
  change_column :table_name, :column_name, :column_type, null: false
end
```

このような変更は、 reversible ではないようで、 db:rollback を実行すると、 IrreversibleMigration が発生してエラーになります。

これを、 reversible な migration を行うような方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reversible な change_column は、少なくとも default や null 制約については存在するようです。

それぞれ、以下のメソッドたちで実現され、

- change_column_null
- change_column_default (の、 `from` と `to` オプション)

掲題の例で言えば、

```
def change
  change_column_null :table_name, :column_name, false, value_for_already_null_record_column
end
```

参考:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211732/3090068

Answer (score 0):

`up` と `down` を定義するのが良いと思います。

```
def up
  change_column :table_name, :column_name, :column_type, null: false
end

def down
  change_column :table_name, :column_name, :column_type, null: true
end
```

(参考)

- [Using the up/down Methods](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-up-down-methods)
- [up/downメソッドを使用する](https://railsguides.jp/active_record_migrations.html#up-down%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)